# Checksum algorithm for multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, checksum

I am looking for a fast checksum function to be used in postgres and thought about Adler-32 and crc32c.

Postgres don't seem to have such functions implemented by default.
The only way i found to implement a hashfunction was like following:

```
SELECT ('x' || encode(digest(column, 'method'), 'hex'))::bit(32)::bigint FROM table
```

The postgres documentation says that there are [all openssl functions supported.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html)
Unfortunatly, none of the algorithms above are included.

Can someone with more experience help me?
My goal is to calculate one checksum of multiple rows which only goal is to be used as integrity check of a subset of data.
The column in question contains data of type 'TEXT'

To clarify my question, here is an example of the table, the expected usage and outcome.

```sql
Example Table:
id |  col | col_2
----------------
1  |'some'| 100
2  |'rndm'|  90
3  |'data'| 400
4  |  'in'|  50
5  |'here'| 600
.
.
.
```

```
Query:
SELECT COUNT(*) as amount, checksum_function(col) as checksum FROM table;
```

```
Expected result:
amount | checksum
-----------------
   20  | hw101h10
```

The datatype of the checksum is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you trying to detect database corruption?

Comment: @Rohit Gupta no, i have to cache some of the data stored in the database and want to check if parts of them are unchanged

Comment: Please clarify: You want *a single* checksum covering *one* column from *multiple* rows? (That's not what the example does.) **Always** declare your version of Postgres. An exact table definition with minimal sample data would be instrumental, too.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that all OpenSSL functions are supported. It says that "any digest algorithm OpenSSL supports is automatically picked up" for use with `digest()`.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe well, that sounds for me as it is automatically added because they are using openssl libs in the background. I might be wrong, thanks for the hint.